# No callback received for onLocationChanged in LocationListener

Tags: java, android, multithreading, location, locationlistener

I am writing a an application that tracks user location with the help of GPS. Here's my implementation of my GPSThread class.

```
package com.example.userpc.roadtracker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


public class GPSThread extends Thread {

    private Context context;
    private volatile boolean stop = true;
    private volatile Location location;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener loclis;
    private final static long dist=0;     //change
    private final static long thread_delay=1*60*1000;       //change

    public static double round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
        value = value * factor;
        long tmp = Math.round(value);
        return (double) tmp / factor;
    }

    public GPSThread(Context c) {
        context = c;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Log.e("GPS", "Enabled "+isGPSEnabled);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, dist, loclis=new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("GPS", "disabled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                location=arg0;
                //location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);     
                //Log.e("Loccation", location.toString()+"hello");
                if(location!=null)
                {

                    // TODO write location to Database
                    double latitude=round(location.getLatitude(),4);
                    double longitude=round(location.getLongitude(),4);
                    Log.e("Location", "Latitude = "+latitude+" Longitude = "+longitude);
                    /*
                     * Implement write to database
                     * Consider making it Thread safe
                     * One helper object and one DB connection
                     * Use singleton pattern
                     */
                    DatabaseHelper dathelp=DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);
                    SQLiteDatabase db=dathelp.getUsableDataBase();
                    try{
                        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO `location` (`longitude`, `latitude`) VALUES ("+longitude+", "+latitude+");");
                        Log.e("Database", "Inserted");
                    }
                    catch(SQLiteConstraintException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("Database", "Same Values");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e("GPS", "Unknown location");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isRunning()
    {
        return !stop;
    }

    public void stopThread() {      
        stop = false;
        interrupt();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(loclis);      //
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run(); 
        Log.e("GPS", "Thread started");
        while (stop) {               
            try {
                Thread.sleep(thread_delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }            
        }
        Log.e("GPS", "Thread stopped");
    }
}
```

**Here are my observations :**

- The onLocationChanged method is only called after I stop the thread.(i.e, when interrupt is called)
- If I dont use the LocationManager.removeUpdates() inside the stopThread() method I get callbacks when the location changes however it is due the locationlisteners that haven't been removed. The most recently added LocationListener however calls the onLocationChanged method only after the thread is stopped.

**My doubts :**

- What is causing this peculiar behaviour?
- Is it because I am using Thread.sleep inside the loop ? (Only when it breaks the onLocationChanged method is called)
- How do I overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show as the code where you create and start the GPSThread?

Comment: @gipsy Here is my call to GPS Thread `GPSThread gp=new GPSThread(getApplicationContext());
   gp.start(); ` It is being called from a Service.

Comment: I am no sure why you are using a dedicated Thread for this. Please take a look at https://gist.github.com/gipsy86147/806299c47fc20de4ec360747e84e8dd4
this works fine for me.